# switching signer off when using parity as development network

Tags: truffle, parity, parity-signer

I successfully created a private network with some accounts with lots of ETH following the [instructions on parity's github](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Private-development-chain)

but when I try to create a transaction the signer wants me to validate each transaction. This is not usable in development.

I tried to use the `--unlock account` option and provided the `--password file`. Parity starts up but transactions simply hang after that.

How can I switch off the signer?

Comment: Unlocking that account is the perfect solution on a dev chain. Which version are you using? Is there any message in the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the signer, you can turn off the whole Wallet User Interface by running Parity with the `--no-ui` flag.

This will disable the signer and force you to sign the transactions or unlock the accounts via RPC.